# Как написать более быстрый код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Описание задачи

> Спортивная школа по синхронному плаванию «Золотая рыбка» приехала в
> детский лагерь «Радость» для проведения летних сборов. Прежде всего
> вожатым требуется расселить спортсменок по комнатам. Главный тренер
> предложил для расселения следующее правило: в комнату заселяют всю
> команду целиком и больше никого другого. Всего приехало n команд
> спортсменок. Количество комнат заданной вместимости в лагере
> ограничено. Определите, получится ли у вожатых расселить детей?

Формат ввода

> В первой строке задано число  n  – число команд спортсменок. Во второй
> строке записаны  n  чисел  a[i]  — количество количество спортсменок в
> i
> -й команде. Далее следует число  k  – количество типов комнат, и  k  пар вида вместимость комнаты, количество таких комнат. Все числа во
> входных данных положительные целые и не превосходят 10000.

Формат вывода

> Выведите Yes, если у вожатых получится расселить спортсменок, и No,
> если не получится.

Ввод

```
3 
1 2 3
1 
2 3
```

Вывод

```
No
```

Мой код:

```
n = int(input())
com_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
k = int(input())
k_list = []

for _ in range(k):
    res = list(map(int, input().split()))
    k_list.extend([res[0]]*res[1])

if len(k_list) < n:
    print('No')
else:
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if sorted(com_list, reverse=True)[i] <= sorted(k_list, reverse=True)[i]:
            s+=1
        else:
            break
    print("No" if s<n else 'Yes')
```

Постоянная проблема со скоростью работы кода и потреблением памяти

Comment: Классная команда по синхронному плаванию из одной спортсменки.

Comment: 1. Не нужно в явном виде хранить все комнаты, достаточно хранить их в виде пар из ввода. В худшем случае вы храните сейчас 10^10 комнат, что долго и по времени и по памяти.

2. Не нужно каждый раз сортировать массивы комнат и команд. Достаточно сделать это единожды, а потом их внутренний порядок изменяться не будет, поэтому всегда можно брать последние элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение на "упакованных" данных без использования сторонних библиотек. Примерно в 1000 раз быстрее на больших данных чем решение от @CrazyElf.

```
# на вход подаются словари, где ключ - это размер, а значение - это соответсвующее количество
def check(teams, rooms):
    # сортируем по размеру, генерируем списки пар (размер, количество)
    teams = sorted(teams.items())
    rooms = sorted(rooms.items())

    team_count = room_quantity = 0
    # цикл пока не кончатся либо команды, либо комнаты
    while (teams or team_count) and (rooms or room_quantity):
        # если все команды этого размера расселили, то берём следующую
        if not team_count    : team_size,     team_count    = teams.pop()
        # если все комнаты этой вместимости заселены, то берём следующую
        if not room_quantity : room_capacity, room_quantity = rooms.pop()
        # команда не помещается в текущую комнату - тогда облом
        if team_size > room_capacity: return "No"

        # уменьшаем оба счетчика оставшихся команд и комнат текущего размера на меньший из них
        decrement = room_quantity if team_count >= room_quantity else team_count
        team_count    -= decrement
        room_quantity -= decrement

    # возвращаем Yes если команд не осталось
    return "No" if teams or team_count else "Yes"

# входные данные пакуем в словари {размер: количество}
input()
teams = {}
for count in map(int, input().split()):
    teams[count] = teams.get(count, 0) + 1
rooms = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    capacity, quantity = map(int, input().split())
    rooms[capacity] = rooms.get(capacity, 0) + quantity

print(check(teams, rooms))

# teams = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
# rooms = {3: 2}
# print(check(teams, rooms))
# teams = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
# rooms = {2: 3}
# print(check(teams, rooms))
# teams = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
# rooms = {3: 3}
# print(check(teams, rooms))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень круто и понятно

Answer (score 3):

Примечание: Наверное, у меня в общем-то по факту ваше же решение, просто записанное короче и понятнее. И ещё как правильно заметил **EzikBro**, у вас на каждом шаге цикла делалась сортировка, что и замедляло проверку.

Допустим, данные уже введены и помещены в соответствующие списки (которые я назвал более понятно). Тогда можно практически в одну строку и вполне понятно задачу решить:

```
teams = [1, 2, 3, 3]
rooms = [2, 3, 2, 1, 4]

print('Yes' 
      if len(rooms)>=len(teams) 
          and all(r >= t for r,t in zip(sorted(rooms, reverse=True), sorted(teams, reverse=True))) 
      else 'No')
```

Чтобы размещение было возможно, должны выполниться два условия, которые и проверяем:

- комнат должно быть не меньше, чем команд
- если попарно сравнить размер отсортированных по убыванию комнат и команд, то размер каждой из комнат должен быть не меньше, чем размер команды

Причём, работать это должно довольно быстро, поскольку проверка закончится не дожидаясь конца перебора, если хоть одна из пар значений не пройдёт условие. Так что сложность = сложности сортировки двух введённых списков + не более `O(n)` на проверку.

Добавил вариант без "распаковки" пар (размер комнаты, количество), чтобы можно было сэкономить память но тут уже в одну строку и без библиотек не получилось:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

teems = [1, 2, 3, 3]
rooms = [(3, 4)]

rooms_gen = (size for room,count in rooms for size in (room for _ in range(count)))
print('Yes' 
      if all(r >= t for r,t in zip_longest(sorted(rooms_gen, reverse=True),sorted(teems, reverse=True), fillvalue=0)) 
      else 'No')
```

Comment: Если есть ограничение по памяти, то такой подход (с "распаковкой" комнат в планарный список) может не пройти. Наоборот, хорошо бы команды с одинаковым количеством участников "запаковать". Ну и на скорость сортировки это тоже не хило так может повлиять.

Comment: @GrAnd Хорошо бы. Но это надо ещё подумать немного )